# how to verify users are in group

Tags: linux, command-line, users, group

we add the following user to the group white_house

kuku , trump , karter

```
usermod -a -G white_house kuku
usermod -a -G white_house trump
usermod -a -G white_house karter
```

as all know we can verify that users was added to the group by

```
grep white_house /etc/group
```

but is it possible to verify it by some command line or more elegant way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use getent

```
getent group white_house
```

or if you want to check a specific users groups you can use `groups`

```
groups karter
```

Answer (score 1):

The following shell function accepts two parameters:

1. a username
2. a group name

It asks for the information about that group with `getent group`, then passes that result to awk. Awk takes the user list (field 4, split by colons) and further splits it into a "users" array, split by commas. It then prints each element (username) of that array on separate lines, which `grep` then inspects for the given username. If the user is found, grep (and thus the whole function) returns 0/success; otherwise, it returns 1/failure. The grep flags mean:

- `-F` -- treat the search text as a fixed string, not a regular expression
- `-x` -- require that the entire line match the search text (avoids false-positive matches, such as "john" and "johnson"
- `-q` -- does not print anything to the screen, but sets the return code appropriately

---

```
function useringroup {
  getent group "$2" |
    awk -F: '{split($4, users, ","); for (name in users) print users[name]}' |
      grep -Fxq "$1"
}
```

Use it like:

```
useringroup myuser mygroup && echo myuser is in mygroup || echo myuser is not in mygroup
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run `id -Gn user_name`:

- **-G** displays all groups for this user_name;
- **-n** displays names not GIDs.

If you need to check if the statement is True then the following (more complex) construction should be helpful `id -Gn user_name | grep group_name && echo "We are good" || echo "user_name is not the member of group_name`.

Comment: What if `user_name` was a member of `white_house_staff` and you were grepping for `white_house`?

Comment: My example was only an example of usage of other commands. You can use regex for more flexible filter of the output. It depends on the system and TS's requirements.